# How to get list object by using only List<T> for 2 Entity?

Tags: c#

In my project, I have 2 Entity objects (delegate for 2 tables in db) as below:

> - Tbl_Person {ID, Name}
> - Tbl_Class {ID, Name, PersonID}

In DAL, I create 2 classes for these Entities, and **write function GetList()**:
- Class Person:

```
public List<Tbl_Person> GetList()
{
    using (var db = DatabaseHelper.DataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var _t = (from info in db.**tbPerson** 
                      select info).ToList();
            return _t.ToList<**Tbl_Person**>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Class MyClass:

```
public List<Tbl_Class> GetList()
{
    using (var db = DatabaseHelper.DataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var _t = (from info in db.**tbClass** 
                      select info).ToList();
            return _t.ToList<**Tbl_Class**>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

If I use 2 classes, I can use GetList() to get list object correctly.
But it seems we have duplicate function GetList() here. What I want just is **only 1 function  GetList() like this**:

```
public List<T> GetList()
{
    using (var db = DatabaseHelper.DataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var _t = (from info in db.**????????** 
                      select info).ToList();
            return _t.ToList<**T**>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, get rid of the *pointless* try/catch blocks. Each of those methods is twice as long as it needs to be, because you're catching exceptions and just rethrowing them - but losing information at the same time! (If you must rethrow, use just `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`.)

Secondly, there's absolutely no point in using a query expression here. You're just interested in the whole table. (Are you *sure* you want to fetch the whole table on each call, by the way?)

Thirdly, assuming these are proper strongly-typed data contexts, I wouldn't expect you to have to specify the type argument for `ToList` in the first place.

So your two methods can *actually be reduced to:

```
// In MyClass
public List<Tbl_Class> GetList()
{
    using (var db = DatabaseHelper.DataContext())
    {
        return db.tbClass.ToList();
    }
}

// In Person
public List<Tbl_Person> GetList()
{
    using (var db = DatabaseHelper.DataContext())
    {
        return db.tbPerson.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now you *could* remove the redundancy here using [`DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx):

```
// In DatabaseHelper:
public static List<T> GetList<T>()
{
    using (var db = DataContext())
    {
        return db.GetTable<T>().ToList();
    }
}

// In MyClass
public List<Tbl_Class> GetList()
{
    return DatabaseHelper.GetList<Tbl_Class>();
}

// In Person
public List<Tbl_Person> GetList()
{
    return DatabaseHelper.GetList<Tbl_Person>();
}
```

It's not really clear whether you *need* the methods in the individual classes...

(In addition to all of this, I'd strongly encourage you to rename your types to remove the `Tbl_` prefix from the mapping. It looks pretty horrible in code, IMO.)

Comment: yes. You definately help me a lot.
 
I can get list with dynamic table now.

For your first opinion, could you please give me an example about try/catch? Because when I tried to debug with my try/catch, it works correct, not happen as your opinion.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThangLang: If you log the stack trace when you've got `throw ex;` you won't see the *original* exception - you'll get that throw line. That loses information. Just using `throw;` works better... but if you're *just* catching an exception to rethrow it, just remove the try/catch block entirely and it'll achieve the same effect without all the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* achieve what you're asking for using Entity Framework and IObjectSet.  I'm not sure it's a sensible thing to want to do though.

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly IObjectContext _context;

    public void Repository(IObjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToList();
    }        
}
```